# Kitaev's Caltech course on condensed matter physics

Tags: condensed-matter, specific-reference

Back in 2007 Prof Kitaev offered a course on advanced condensed matter physics with very well hand-written notes (see the syllabus and first page below).  I only have the first few weeks of the notes and wish to have the rest for self-study.  Unfortunately Prof Kitaev seems no longer offer this course nor does he have the plan to publish it into a book (those who are close to him should encourage him to do so!).  I have tried to reach Prof Kitaev but you know famous professors are too busy to check up emails from somebody he is not acquainted with.  I am trying my luck here to see whether there is anybody who happens to have taken the entire 3-quarter course and willing to share the rest part with me.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about educational or career advice.

Comment: educational or career advice?  I am aiming for a comprehensive study on condensed matter physics and to me Kitaev's notes are better than books.

Comment: Probably. But at any rate, this is not within the scope of this site. You could ask in [chat] though.

Comment: @PhysicsMath did you write also to the teaching assistant? Maybe you are more lucky there.

Comment: @DavidZ: Sure!  I will check that!  Many thanks for pointing that out.  I was not aware of its existence!

Comment: @ungerade: Unfortunately the TA has left academia...